# Show the data in the Template according to the value of the select

Tags: python, django

Hi friends i need help as i am new to django!
I need to show the information that I have saved in a table according to the option chosen from a `select`. When selecting the select option in the template I save the value in a variable using JavaScript (I do that without problems). I can't get the value of that variable to the `get_context_data` method, to later show it in my template.
JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {  
    $('select[name="reporteFecha"]').on('change', function () {
        var fecha = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.pathname,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'search_fecha',
                'fecha': fecha
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        })
    });
});
```

Views code:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
   
        ### I need to obtain within this function the value of the select in a variable ###
        CE = ConsumoElect.objects.filter(fecha = *value obtained from JavaScript*)
        
        context = {
            'CE': CE,

            'title': 'Reporte de Control de Electricidad',
            'entity': 'Reporte Electricidad',
            'list_url': reverse_lazy('cont_elect:Reporte_list'),
            'form': ReportForm(),
        }  
        return context
```

I need to obtain in a variable inside the `get_context_data` the value that I capture with the JavaScript to later be able to show it in the template

Comment: Don't get exactly what you want to do. Your Ajax call is asynchronous, template rendering is synchronous so you can not change the values in your context data after the template is rendered.

Maybe I missunderstood your point maybe a more explicit example would help

Comment: Hello friend, what I need is to show in my `template` all the information of the `ConsumoElect model` but that depends on what is selected in the `select`. I have modified the `get_context_data` code for a better understanding of what I need

Comment: So in this case you have to get the informations from the POST If I remember well you whould have them in self.request.POST

Comment: You have a reason, with the `post` method I get the value of the `select` (I already tried it), but I don't know how to take that value from the `post` to `get_context_data`, because the result that I show in the `template` I get from the dictionary that I generate in `get_context_data`

Comment: Oh I think I got what you want to do. I will send an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watching some video tutorials I found one that helped me solve the problem (although it does not use JavaScript), the method is not a class of the view but a function.

```
def Reporte3View(req):
    fecha = req.POST.get('fecha')
    ConsE = list(TipoPGD.objects.all().values('id', 'name'))
    lista_CE=[]
    
    if fecha == None:
        for item in ConsE:
            B = ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=item['id'])
            lista_CE.append(B)
    else:
        for item in ConsE:
            B = ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=item['id'], fecha=fecha)
            lista_CE.append(B)

    context = {
        'lista_CE': lista_CE,
        'entity': 'Reporte Electricidad',
        'title': 'Reporte de Control de Electricidad',
        'list_url': reverse_lazy('cont_elect:Reporte3'),
        'form': Report3Form(),
        #'form': Report3Form(initial={'fecha': '2023-04-01'}), # Me muestra este valor
    }
    form = Report3Form()
    return render(req, 'Reporte/reporte_elect3.html', context )
```

Answer (score 0):

The get_context_data is made for GET requests, not POST requests. It's basically not made for doing calculation or to manage the render of a POST. To do so, you have to redefine the post() method. In your case you will have something like that:

````py
class YourClass(view):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
            It's useless to call the super get context data if you redefine it just after.
            Here you just create the "base" context (that you will have on GET and POST request).
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'title': 'Reporte de Control de Electricidad',
            'entity': 'Reporte Electricidad',
            'list_url': reverse_lazy('cont_elect:Reporte_list'),
            'form': ReportForm(),
        }) # You update the super context_data to not override it
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Here you redefine the behavior of the POST request
        """

        CE = ConsumoElect.objects.filter(fecha=request.POST.get('fecha')

        context = self.get_context_data() #retrieving the "base" context
        context['CE'] = CE
        return render(request, 'templatename.html', context)
        
    ```
````

Comment: OK my friend, in the post method I get the value in the `CE` variable (it works perfectly, I've tried it before), but I don't know how to create the "base" context (that you will have on GET and POST request) in the get_context_data method

Comment: I appreciate her help and I ask for a little patience to understand since I am really new to django